# java test compiling error:'bad signature ¾4s9' when upgrade spring boot 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-2

I have a gradle project like this:

```
root
  |
  |---- projectA
  |   |
  |   |----main
  |
  |---- projectB
  |   |
  |   |----test
 ...
```

projectA is upgrading springboot 1.0 to 2.0
projectA gradle.build is like this:

```
...
jar {
    enabled = true
}
...
```

and projectB test is depend on project A
projectB gradle.build is like this:

```
...
dependencies {
    testCompile project(':projectA')
}
...
```

a compile error happened when running ./gradlew :projectB:test
[image: bad signature ¾4s9]

the error message is:

```
xxx.TestSupport.java:20: error: cannot access QueryManager
bad class file xxx/xxx/QueryManager.class
bad signature ¾4s9
```

the TestSupport.java is in projectB
the QueryManager is in projectA. And the querymanager class use lombok and ea.async.

the TestSupport.java's content is:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {
        MysqlConfigurationSelector.class
},
properties = {"query.mysql.nio.enable=true","query.mysql.port=9011"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class TestSupport {}
```

I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Could you please share the contents of the possible erroneous class?

Comment: the error message is:'xxx.TestSupport.java:20: error: cannot access QueryManager', the TestSupport.java is in projectB, the QueryManager is in projectA. And the querymanager class use lombok and ea.async. @aribeiro

Comment: Apparently the issue is with the QueryManager.class file. Have you tried to compile projectA on its own first, to see if the error also appears?

Comment: I've tried. './gradlew :projectA:jar'  build successful@aribeiro

Comment: Could you please share the contents of your `TestSupport.java` file?

Comment: @aribeiro contents is appended

Comment: Make sure that you build the app with up-to-date JDK version. Unlike Spring Boot 1 Spring Boot 2 requires Java 8+

Comment: @dayu why is your test class an `abstract` class? Also, in your test class, I can't see any reference to your `QueryManager` class.

Comment: @aribeiro and Nikolai, I have solved the problem, the eaAsync lib ((https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async)  newest version 1.2.3 make the compile error. when downgrade to 1.0.5, the problem solved. thanks for your help and time

Comment: @dayu that's awesome! Then please post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
the eaAsync lib ((github.com/electronicarts/ea-async) newest version 1.2.3 make the compile error. when downgrade to 1.0.5, the problem solved.